# EF Core Database First

Tags: c#, ef-database-first, ef-core-2.1

We are using EF Core with database which constantly changes by database administrators. So we can't always check changes in this database. What is the best approach to use EF Core with such database?
We tried to use Database First approach but we can't always regenerate model classes in project.

Comment: There's nothing you can do. Create a Database project in Visual Studio (assuming Enterprise edition is available) and ask the administrators to ensure changes are made there so you can at least know which changes are done, when and by whom

Comment: Its a cool thing, its called "communication" and "planning".

Comment: I have no personal experience with it but I planned to try [Evolve](https://github.com/lecaillon/Evolve). Looks promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dit down with management and talk about it. I see no way to work when the db constantly changes.

The way we do it here now is that special people are responsibel for:

- Generating changescripts that automatically are applicable
- Making sure the EF model is kept in sync.
- When neeed we have the ability to give every developer his own environment AND have environments for valiation.

There is NO Way to do any work when you work against a database that 3rd parties are constantly changing, and it gets worse if you are more people.

Comment: There is "no official way" from Microsoft (which is shame in my opinion). Non-official tools for Database-First exists: [Evolve](https://github.com/lecaillon/Evolve) for example.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can track changes in your database is by doing source control for it. At least, then you know what changed. Still not the best scenario overall when someone else modifies database with poor communication.